# My Left Join is dropping rows when trying to join based on two keys and a date range

Tags: sql, teradata

When a client sets up a payment plan they are sent a corresponding confirmation letter of their payment plan within 5 days of set up. The Plan Set Up table can have duplicate plan set up dates. I only care about bringing back DISTINCT Plan Set Up Dates for every Loan Number from Table A.

Lets say Table A has a distinct population of 5000. I want to test if a corresponding letter was sent out within 5 days. If no corresponding letter is found in table B within that timeframe it should bring back null values.

I care about letters A, B, C in Table B and will JOIN based on LOAN_NUMBER, CLIENT_NUMBER

Table A : Plan Set Up

| Loan_Number* | Client_Number* | Plan_Set_Up_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 321 | 01/15/2021 |
| 12345 | 321 | 01/15/2021 |
| 12345 | 321 | 01/15/2021 |
| 12345 | 321 | 06/15/2022 |
| 12345 | 321 | 06/15/2022 |
| 12345 | 321 | 06/15/2022 |
| 12345 | 321 | 09/15/2022 |

Table B : Letters

| Loan_Number* | Client_Number* | Letter_Name | Letter_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 321 | A | 01/15/2021 |
| 12345 | 321 | A | 06/15/2021 |

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| Loan_Number* | Client_Number* | Plan_Set_Up_Date | Letter_Nme | Letter_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 321 | 01/15/202 | A | 01/15/2021 |
| 12345 | 321 | 06/15/2022 | A | 06/15/2021 |
| 12345 | 321 | 09/15/2022 | NULL | NULL |

QUERY

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE
                A.LOAN_NUMBER,
                A.CLIENT_NUMBER,
                B.LETTER_NAME,
                B.LETTER_DATE
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
       ON A.LOAN_NUMBER = B.LOAN_NUMBER AND A.CLIENT_NUMBER = B.CLIENT_NUMBER
       AND (B.LETTER_DATE IS NULL OR (B.LETTER_DATE BETWEEN A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE AND    (CAST(A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE AS DATE) + INTERVAL '5' DAY)))
WHERE B.LETTER_NAME IN ('A','B','C')
```

My result set is bringing back less than 5000 records (distinct population in Table A)

Since I can only join on LOAN_NUMBER and CLIENT_NUMBER between both tables, I want to set some type of condition that will say IF B.LETTER_DATE IS BETWEEN A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE AND A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE + 5 assign that letter to A, else NULL.

Comment: WHERE clauses are applied ***after*** the LEFT JOIN, by which time some rows have NULL values and so those rows get excluded. Move that WHERE clause to be part of the JOIN predicate with an AND condition.

Answer (score 0):

move the table b filter to the where clause rather than on the join.  If the filter is on the left join it will remove records not matching the left join criteria from the result set.  you want to see all the records from the left join then apply the where filter to remove unwanted records.  I added parens to separate the filter logic.   the or condition was never reached.

```
declare @tmpA as table(LOAN_NUMBER int, CLIENT_NUMBER int, PLAN_CREATE_DATE date)
declare @tmpB as table(LOAN_NUMBER int, CLIENT_NUMBER int, PLAN_CREATE_DATE date, LETTER_NAME varchar(1), LETTER_DATE date)

insert into @tmpA
(
LOAN_NUMBER,CLIENT_NUMBER,PLAN_CREATE_DATE
)
values(12345,321,'01/15/2021')
,(12345,321,'01/15/2021')
,(12345,321,'06/15/2022')
,(12345,321,'06/15/2022')
,(12345,321,'06/15/2022')
,(12345,321,'09/15/2022')

insert into @tmpB
(
LOAN_NUMBER,CLIENT_NUMBER,LETTER_NAME,PLAN_CREATE_DATE,LETTER_DATE
)
values(12345,321, 'A', '01/15/2021', '01/15/2021')
,(12345,321,    'A','06/15/2021','06/15/2021')

SELECT DISTINCT --A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE,
                A.LOAN_NUMBER,
                A.CLIENT_NUMBER,
                B.LETTER_NAME
                --,B.LETTER_DATE
FROM @tmpA A
LEFT JOIN @tmpB B
       ON A.LOAN_NUMBER = B.LOAN_NUMBER AND A.CLIENT_NUMBER = B.CLIENT_NUMBER
WHERE (
       B.LETTER_NAME IN ('A','B','C')
       AND B.LETTER_DATE IS NULL
       )

       OR (
         B.LETTER_DATE   BETWEEN A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE 
         AND    DATEADD(DAY,5,A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE) 
       )
```

Comment: I don't think this will produce the expected output. As other comments say, the solution will be to move the conditions into the join, not out of the join. This also seems to confuse precedence. As it is written, only the `LETTER_DATE BETWEEN` condition is even being used, since `B.LETTER_NAME IN ('A','B','C') AND B.LETTER_DATE IS NULL` will always be false for this sample data.

Answer (score 0):

As others noted simply move the condition on the inner table to ON (conditions on the outer table are usually placed in WHERE)

```
From A
LEFT JOIN B
  ON A.LOAN_NUMBER = B.LOAN_NUMBER AND A.CLIENT_NUMBER = B.CLIENT_NUMBER
 AND B.LETTER_NAME IN ('A','B','C')
 AND B.LETTER_DATE BETWEEN A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE AND A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE + 5
```

Another way (may be easier to understand) is to apply all WHERE conditions before joining. You can also apply DISTINCT before the join:

```
SELECT 
   A.*,
   B.LETTER_NAME,
   B.LETTER_DATE
FROM
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      PLAN_CREATE_DATE,
      LOAN_NUMBER,
      CLIENT_NUMBER
   From A
 ) AS A
LEFT JOIN 
 ( 
   SELECT
      LOAN_NUMBER
      CLIENT_NUMBER,
      LETTER_NAME,
      LETTER_DATE
   FROM B
   WHERE B.LETTER_NAME IN ('A','B','C')
 ) AS B
  ON A.LOAN_NUMBER = B.LOAN_NUMBER AND A.CLIENT_NUMBER = B.CLIENT_NUMBER
 AND B.LETTER_DATE BETWEEN A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE AND A.PLAN_CREATE_DATE + 5
```